# Kafka Schema registry & spark continuous stream Integration, Exception: circular reference of class class org.apache.avro.Schema

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to apply spark continuous streaming using Kafka as a read source on a project uses Schema registry. and my Kafka message extends `SpecificAvroRecord` [which has a Schema field (org.apache.avro.Schema)].

As far as I understand, self-references are not supported by spark. so, what's the best way to integrate Kafka Schema registry [specific record] with spark continuous streaming?

**my test code:**

```
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("testpro")
        .master("local[2]").getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> df = spark.readStream()
        .format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.68.1:9092,192.168.204.1:9092")
        .option("subscribe", "testTopic")
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest").load();

    Dataset<Data> messages = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").map(value -> new Data(value.toString()), Encoders.bean(Data.class));
```

**Message class**

```
public class Data extends SpecificAvroRecord {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  public String name;

  public Data() {}
   ........setters and getters and string constructore
```

**SpecificAvroRecord:**

```
public abstract class SpecificAvroRecord extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase {
  protected Schema schema;
}
```

**Exception :**

````
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot have circular references in bean class, but got the circular reference of class class org.apache.avro.Schema
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.javaBean(ExpressionEncoder.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.bean(Encoders.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.bean(Encoders.scala)
    at com.eventumsolutions.nms.spark.services.analyzer.app.contStr.main(contStr.java:50)
    ```
````

Comment: You'll want to exclude Avro (and kafka-clients) dependency from Schema Registry dependency, but also casting the value to a string, then trying to deserialize it with Avro wouldnt work

Comment: could you clarify what do you mean by "You'll want to exclude Avro"
please?

Comment: As a Java dependency using Maven/Gradle, assuming you are using them